# Scrapy - Grab Child Element - Grabing Wrong part of CSS Selector

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to grab " "Brick Bank" from the tag below

```
<a href="/sets/10251-1/Brick-Bank"><span>10251: </span> Brick Bank</a>
```

with my Scrapy Spider object below:
        import scrapy

```
class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider): #we take the Spider class provided by Scrapy and make a subclass out of it called BrickSetSpider. 
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016/']

    def parse(self, response): # in the html, css is the easier option and we find the.set and use for our selector
        SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR): 
            pass

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 a ::text'
            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

but I am getting(as you can see below)- 'Name: 10251', not Brick-Bank? Very new to this, so not sure why - I am following a tutorial that returned the correct name

```
 2018-08-20 19:56:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://brick
set.com/sets/year-2016/>
{'name': '10251: '}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a common mistake for css selectors where the spaces are very important for the actual result of the selector.

```
'h1 a ::text'
```

That says to get `text` from all inner elements below `a`, but what you need is:

```
'h1 a::text'
```

That says to only get the text element from the `a` tag

Comment: @pes04 please remember to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks